# How to get the id from the slider when press next button by using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Below is the code that i tried to get the template id from the slider wrapper. Whenever user choose the active template which is current template, how to get the id from there? 
I tried to use the html way but it always give me the template id is no 3 which is always give the last template id

This is the html code:

```
<!-- slider-->
        <div id="slider-wrapper">
            <div id="slider">
                <div class="template">
                    <h3>Chronological Resume</h3>
                    Traditional Resume Template
                    <img src="images/resumes_image/chronological.png" id="1" alt="Chronological Resume" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="template" value="1"/>
                </div>
                <div class="template">
                    <h3>Functional Resume</h3>
                    Skills-based Resume Template
                    <img src="images/resumes_image/functional.png" id="2" alt="Functional Resume" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="template" value="2"/>
                </div>
                <div class="template">
                    <h3>Combination Resume</h3>
                    Combination of Chronological Resume & Functional Resume
                    <img src="images/resumes_image/combination.png" id="3" alt="Combination Resume" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="template" value="3"/>
                </div>  
            </div> <!-- close for slider-->
        </div> <!-- close for slider-wrapper-->
        <div id="nav">
            <div id="button-previous"><img src="images/icons/prev.png" alt="previous" /></div>
        <div id="button-next"><img src="images/icons/next.png" alt="next" /></div>
```

Code Trying to Retrieve Slider Number:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $template = $_POST['template']; 
    echo $template; 
    exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: where in your code are you trying to get the slider number?  I don't see any attempts to get it

Comment: i tried to insert the code in the html area which is  <input type="hidden" name="template" value="3"/> under every images. but it always give the last template id whenever i try to retrieve it

Comment: again... when and where are you trying to retrieve it?

Comment: is that PHP?  that doesn't look like jquery and javascript like your tags suggest

Comment: yes, combination of php and javascript. Because i am using the slider which is require javascript. so i think about maybe there is a way to retrieve it from the javascript .active class there?

Comment: I could show you how to get the slider number with just javascript / jquery , but I do not know PHP.  If you want a javascript solution , please edit the question with your best attempt in javascript to get the slider number and I'll answer.  If you want a PHP answer , then leave the question and I'll re-tag for you so a PHP developer can help you

Answer (score 0):

a pure javascript/jQuery solution:

```
var sliderNum = $('.active > #template').val();
```

Comment: $(".button-next").click(function(){
  var slider_num = $('.active > .template').val();
  alert(slider_num);
 });

Comment: when i alerted that slider_num, it shows undefined. how do i get the exact no?